# Problem to add an object from firebase in a List

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**TestActivity.java**

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference fireBaseRef = ConfigurationFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    private Button buttonTest;
    private Question question;
    List<Question> questionsList = new ArrayList();
    private String name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_simulado);

        generateQuestions();
        buttonTest= findViewById(R.id.buttonTest);


        buttonTest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(TestActivity.this, listaQuestion.get(0).getQuestion().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
        });


    }   

    public List<Question> generateQuestions() {
        DatabaseReference questionRef = fireBaseRef.child("questions");
        questionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                question = dataSnapshot.child("id").child("1").getValue(Question.class);
                name = question.getQuestion().toString();

                Question objectQuestion = new Question();
                objectQuestion.setQuestion(name);
                objectQuestion.setOptionA(question.getOptionA());
                objectQuestion.setOptionB(question.getOptionB());
                objectQuestion.setOptionC(question.getOptionC());
                objectQuestion.setOptionD(question.getOptionD());
                objectQuestion.setResult(question.getResult());
                questionsList.add(objectQuestion);


            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {


            }
        });
        return questionsList;

    }
}
```

I keep getting error `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0` when i try to show a toast using the List, but with the variable name it shows. The class Question only have getters and setters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting 0 because you are returning the list before the data is fetched, see that firebase runs this asynchronous and it gets some time in onDataChange() to fetch the data in order to return it. Please read this answer I posted yesterday [How do I pass data out of the onDataChange method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52348470/how-do-i-pass-data-out-of-the-ondatachange-method/52348502#52348502)  is the same issue.

Also please check this answer from Frank van Puffelen [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list)

Comment: Thansk for the help and sorry for the duplicate question, I think I was looking the wrong way in the forum

Comment: No problem Lucas, we are here to help you and assist in what you need